# #1054 - Unknown column 'vi.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I got error "#1054 - Unknown column 'vi.id' in 'on clause'" for below query any one help pls

```
SELECT DISTINCT vtiger_salesorder.salesorder_no
FROM vtiger_salesorder
LEFT JOIN ( 
        select group_concat(TheSum)
        FROM (
            SELECT concat(productname, ', ',
                   SUM(vtiger_inventoryproductrel.quantity)) AS TheSum
            FROM vtiger_inventoryproductrel, vtiger_products
            where vtiger_products.productid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid
            GROUP BY vtiger_products.productid
        ) T 
) As vi ON vi.id=vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid
```

Comment: your inner select doesn't have an `id` field. the ONLY thing it's returning is the group_concat field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your id is refer to `group_contat(TheSum)`, in this part of your subquery:

```
select group_concat(TheSum)
```

add alias `id`